# Error while moving files from one folder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query to move files from one folder(*Source*) to another(*Destination*)
I have given permission on both source and destination to network services and local services, I get an error

> The system cannot find the file specified

I have tested the folders to see if I am able to to access the files and I was able to, it seems when I get the files it works. It is when I try to move the files to the Destination folder, I get this error.

My query below is as follow, I create a temp table to link to my source folder and insert its contents into it, I then filter it out into another temp table, where I then get the files I want to move and then use a cursor to iterate through it and move the files.

I hope this can assist.

```
Create Table #tmpDir
                (
                ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                fName varchar(400)
                )
         Declare @dir varchar(100)
         Declare @folderPath varchar(500)
         set @folderPath = '\\Server1\Documents\Ocs\Inbox\'
         set @dir = 'DIR ' + '"' + @folderPath + '"'
         print @dir
         INSERT #tmpDir EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @dir
         DELETE FROM #tmpDir where ID < 6
         SELECT SUBSTRING(FName,40,100) fileName2
                into #THIS
         FROM #tmpDir
         WHERE FName not like '%<DIR>%' 
         and FName not like '%bytes%' and FName is not null

Delete #THIS Where fileName2 Not Like '%_MyFiles%'


Declare @FileMove varchar(100)
Declare cur cursor for

  Select fileName2 From #THIS

Open cur

Fetch next from cur into @FileMove

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN

Declare @cmd varchar(1000)
   set @cmd = 'Move /y "\\Server1\Documents\Ocs\Inbox\' + @FileMove + '     "\\Server1\ImportMac\Inbox"'
   EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd

        Fetch next from cur into  @FileMove
                 END
Close cur
Deallocate cur

Drop Table #tmpDir, #THIS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a double quote at the end of the source file name for your `move` command:

```
set @cmd = 'Move /y "\\Server1\Documents\Ocs\Inbox\' + @FileMove + '"     "\\Server1\ImportMac\Inbox"'
```

Comment: Oh Wow! To think it was something so small, I will be more vigilant thanks for all your help @MartinParkin